# WebDriverException: Message: 'Can not connect to the ChromeDriver'. Error in utils.is_connectable(self.port):

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

**I am trying to use the chromedriver 2.10 to run my tests on Chrome Browser Version 35.0.1916.114 On CentOS machine**

/home/varunm/EC_WTF_0.4.10/EC_WTF0.4.10_Project/wtframework/wtf/drivers/chromedriver

Actually I fixed the path issue, because the error message was different if the issue was with path

```
    def start(self):
    """
    Starts the ChromeDriver Service.

    :Exceptions:
     - WebDriverException : Raised either when it can't start the service
       or when it can't connect to the service
    """
    env = self.env or os.environ
    try:
        self.process = subprocess.Popen([
          self.path,
          "--port=%d" % self.port] +
          self.service_args, env=env, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    except:
        raise WebDriverException(
            "ChromeDriver executable needs to be available in the path. \
            Please download from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html\
            and read up at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver")
    count = 0
    while not utils.is_connectable(self.port):
        count += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        if count == 30:
             raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the ChromeDriver")
```

If the path was wrong I will receive some other error, but now the error is while making the connection

Comment: Can you reformat your question, it is very hard to read as is. Sounds like you did not put chromedriver in the right path. Where did you put it? How are you specifying the location?

Comment: /home/varunm/EC_WTF_0.4.10/EC_WTF0.4.10_Project/wtframework/wtf/drivers/chromedriver

Comment: @SiKing did you understand my issue now? Thanks for looking into this. I have already handled the issue with the path. But now the error is with making connections to the chromedriver. My tests work fine on firefox

Comment: There are two chromedriver libraries for linux, for 32 and 64 bit systems. Are you using the right one? You can download them here http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.10/

Comment: Yes,  I have done the 64 bit Chrome driver ... my centos virtual machine is 64 bit too ..

Comment: Does the Chrome browser version matter? ? I have the latest version of Chrome browser

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**For Linux** 
 1. Check you have installed latest version of chrome brwoser-> **"chromium-browser -version"** 
 2. If not, install latest version of chrome **"sudo apt-get install chromium-browser"**
 3. get appropriate version of chrome driver from following link http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
 4. Unzip the chromedriver.zip
 5. Move the file to /usr/bin/ directory **sudo mv chromedriver /usr/bin/**
 6. Goto /usr/bin/ directory and you would need to run something like "**chmod a+x chromedriver**" to mark it executable. 
 7. finally you can execute the code.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
print driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
driver.quit()
display.stop()
```

Comment: What is the pyvirtualdisplay? I run code without it and chome doesn't run still

Comment: @alexche8 I guess that is for the people who run their tests on a virtual server(with no display)

Comment: @alex, pyvirtuadisplay performs all graphical operations in memory without showing any screen output.  Let me know your issue.

Comment: Had to use some options https://stackoverflow.com/a/60168019/1454173

Answer (score 19):

Verify the line *127.0.0.1  localhost* is added to your /etc/hosts file and uncommented. This was the issue for some of my colleagues, and I was able to reproduce it after I've removed this line. Adding it back solved the problem.

Comment: holy crap it was this in my case

Answer (score 4):

open /etc/hosts file and
check 127.0.0.1 localhost have matched

Answer (score 1):

```
Confirm that your chrome version matches.
If you are using Chrome version 73, please download ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.20
If you are using Chrome version 72, please download ChromeDriver 2.46 or ChromeDriver 72.0.3626.69
If you are using Chrome version 71, please download ChromeDriver 2.46 or ChromeDriver 71.0.3578.137
```

Download: http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that you are not using the latest `ChromeDriver`. For that, navigate to https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/.