# Can't fetch URL in chrome browser

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I wrote this code which is in selenium webdriver in python.

I want to open link in chrome browser, the browser is getting started but can't fetch url.

```
def setUp(self):
    self.browser = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/google-chrome")
    browser = self.browser
    browser.implicitly_wait(5)
    browser.get("http://www.google.com")
```

This gives this error:

```
ERROR: test_start (__main__.Saletest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sale_test.py", line 16, in setUp
self.browser = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/google-chrome")
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-    packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 60, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.py", line 88, in start
os.path.basename(self.path) + "'")
WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the 'google-chrome'
```

Comment: so what's the solution , I want to run in chrome webdriver

Comment: You need the ChromeDriver binary, not the chrome browser binary. Please read the question I linked

Comment: Don't think this is an exact duplicate of [Running webdriver chrome with Selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255929/running-webdriver-chrome-with-selenium) - here we have a Google Chrome vs chromedriver confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Basically Selenium find your binary, but can't connect to it.

Try this, this seems to correspond to your problem :)
[WebDriverException: Message: 'Can not connect to the ChromeDriver'. Error in utils.is_connectable(self.port):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900922/webdriverexception-message-can-not-connect-to-the-chromedriver-error-in-uti)

Comment: I also made my file executable and followed the link steps but same error arrises

Comment: Did you read the link of Noel Segura ? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255929/running-webdriver-chrome-with-selenium)
Here is some doc too http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver

Answer (score 0):

The first argument that `webdriver.Chrome` expects to be provided with is the `executable_path` - **a path to the `chromedriver`**, but you are passing a path to the `Chrome` itself.

The `executable_path` argument is optional. In case `chromedriver` is in `PATH` and selenium can automatically find it, you don't need to explicitly state where it is located.

If you want to provide a *custom `Chrome` browser executable* instead, define the `Chrome` binary location via `ChromeOptions`:

```
options = Options()
options.binary_location = "/path/to/google-chrome"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

And, just for completeness, here is how would the setup look in case you have a custom `chromedriver` path and a custom `Chrome` browser binary path:

```
options = Options()
options.binary_location = "/path/to/google-chrome"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/path/to/chromedriver", 
                          chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: It is giving an error like " Global name option is not defined "

Comment: @sakibkeriwala oops, fixed that.

Comment: Thanks the problem is solved with another code , thanks for your support