# Selenium python: Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to run a selenium test with python script, but I am receiving the following error when executing the test:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/html/selenium-scripts/example.py", line 13, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__self.service.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 88, in start
raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service chromedriver
```

Please advice how to resolve this

Comment: Please look at this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624689/selenium-python-can-not-connect-to-the-service-s-self-path

Comment: You are linking to my question?

Comment: Sorry, wrong link ;)
There is a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900922/webdriverexception-message-can-not-connect-to-the-chromedriver-error-in-uti

Comment: Is it solved? because I have the same problem

Comment: Can someone solve this. I have same issue on Mac OS X

Answer (score 7):

After googling for a while, and trying various solutions. I found the one that worked for me at here:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2903#issuecomment-272112510

As mentioned in that comment, try to add `127.0.0.1 localhost` to /etc/hosts

Answer (score 2):

For MAC System:
Change the host file to default as below:
1. Command+Shift+G go to  /private/etc/hosts
2.Open in Text File
3. File > Save as and uncheck the box for “If no extension is provided use txt” and rename hosts
4.Go Terminal  execute command cat /etc/hosts
Check if it shows

```
##
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting. Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

Comment: You should provide everything necessary in the answer itself, not just part of it. In other words, answers should be self-contained.

Answer (score 1):

For windows  C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Open as Administrator a Notepad then open the file hosts and do all the changes you need, in my particular case was:

```
0.0.0.0            localhost
```

to:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

that fixed my problem with Selenium.