# Webdrivers not working with Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have tried various SO solutions on going about this. 
System Config:

- MacOS Catalina
- Python 3.7.6 (Anaconda)
- Selenium 3.141
- Chrome v81, ChromeDriver v81.

  Error: Can not connect to the service chromedriver.

I have tried the same with various driver and browers: Gecko/Firefox(Fresh install), Safaridriver/Safar - all with the same error.

The chromedriver, geckodriver are in PATH as well as usr/local/bin.

Code to reproduce:

```
from selenium import webdriver
chromedriver = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
```

I have also tried various solutions, `executable_path=chromedriver` and `hosts file with localhost 127.0.0.1 entry`.

chromedriver by itself runs perfectly, without any issues, it just can't seem to connect to Selenium.

Any help, if possible will be appreciated.

Expected results: `Selenium connects to driver`

Actual Results: `raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path) 
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service /usr/local/bin/chromedriver`

Solutions already tried:

- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41047957/selenium-and-python3-chromedriver-raises-message-can-not-connect-to-the-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49883992/chromedriver-not-working-on-python-selenium)
- [Chromedriver not working on python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49883992/chromedriver-not-working-on-python-selenium)
- [Python Selenium "Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path in linux server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50753093/python-selenium-can-not-connect-to-the-service-s-self-path-in-linux-server)

And other solutions on SO.

Comment: Have you tried to do this? https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2903#issuecomment-272112510

Comment: I have tried that, it focused on localhost address in the hosts file. It didn't do anything, everything was already the way it was supposed to be. @Naveen

Comment: Can you try to initiate Chrome as per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39428368/7964299?

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work. The error remained the same. @Naveen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While experimenting to make this work, I somehow messed up while creating venv and docker images. Python as a whole got corrupted, along with chrome drivers. Had to reset the system.

That somehow has solved my problem with selenium. If anyone else finds the answer to this bug, be sure to drop your solution.

Until then, this was my update about how I got it working.