# Why am I getting JavaScript Puppeteer error: "ECONNREFUSED"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, puppeteer

I'm trying to run a simple test Puppeteer script where I open Google Chrome and then close it by doing this:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch(
    {executablePath: '/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'},
    {headless: false},
    {ignoreHTTPSErrors: true});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com');

  await browser.close();
})().catch(error => { console.error("Something bad happend...", error); });;
```

However, the error I get is:

```
Something bad happend... ErrorEvent {
  target:
   WebSocket {
     _events:
      [Object: null prototype] { open: [Function], error: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 2,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     readyState: 3,
     protocol: '',
     _binaryType: 'nodebuffer',
     _closeFrameReceived: false,
     _closeFrameSent: false,
     _closeMessage: '',
     _closeTimer: null,
     _closeCode: 1006,
     _extensions: {},
     _receiver: null,
     _sender: null,
     _socket: null,
     _bufferedAmount: 0,
     _isServer: false,
     _redirects: 0,
     url:
      'ws://(my IP address)/devtools/browser/ae12c970-126d-463c-af41-1ab49be03575',
     _req: null },
  type: 'error',
  message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED (my IP address)',
  error:
   { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED (my IP address)
       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)
     errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     syscall: 'connect',
     address: '(my IP address)',
     port: (my port)} }
```

---

Additionally, I've also tried running my code as:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({executablePath: "/mnt/c/'Program Files (x86)'/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com');

  await browser.close();
})();
```

But I get the error:

```
(node:2178) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch the browser process! spawn /mnt/c/'Program Files (x86)'/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe ENOENT
```

I'm fairly new to javascript and puppeteer, so I may be missing something obvious. This is part of a larger effort to automate filling in a form online, so it seems that puppeteer is the way to go. However, if anyone has a better suggestion for how to do that, it's much appreciated. Any ideas?

---

**EDIT 1:** I downloaded Firefox and linked to that instead of Chrome. When running with the Task Manager open, after a few seconds, a popup would occur. Additionally, Firefox would only be shown as running once that box popped up but not before it. You can see that process in the video linked below:

https://vimeo.com/user119175210/review/436574888/590a38ef10

Comment: Do you have a firewall installed? Is the port opened?

Comment: @Bsalex No firewall, I'm also running locally (no SSH)

Comment: There's no need to hide your IP address. Everyone knows it's `127.0.0.1`. 

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me as well. I disabled my antivirus and firewall and then it worked.

Comment: It just a connection error, when it does not able to reach the url or any specific port then it gives ECONNREFUSED ERROR whic is TCP connection error.

Comment: yes @praveen2609 the time i got that error ,i was not able to reach the url as my firewall was blocking the connection, dont know why tho :)

Comment: I'm not using a firewall, not sure why I would be getting that error. I tried using the built-in chromium from puppeteer initially but I was getting weird errors, so instead I linked to my google chrome. Any idea why that would be giving me problems?

Comment: so are you saying that you are not getting wierd errors in google chrome but getting errors in chromium?

Comment: @Arun It wasn't working with Chrome, Chromium, and Firefox. I've made some progress following the link on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624689/selenium-python-can-not-connect-to-the-service-s-self-path